# Need help in designing Backbone Model

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am pretty new to Backbone.js and here I am trying to design a Model to use in an application. Below is the situation:

I have the following tables:
1) Category, Product, Customer and Order.

Each Category has one or more Product.

On the Home Screen I choose to display all the categories, then the user clicks on a given Category and I show him/her the list of Product.

Here is what I tried:

```
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url : 'http://localhost:8090/OrderManagement/om/categories'
    });

    var Category = Backbone.Model.extend({

        urlRoot : "http://localhost:8090/OrderManagement/om/categories"

    });

    var CategoryList = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:'ul',
        el : '.content',
        render : function() {
            var that = this;
            var categories = new Categories();
            categories.fetch({
                success : function(categories) {
                    var template = _.template($('#category-list-template')
                            .html(), {
                        categories : categories.models
                    });
                    that.$el.html(template);
                }
            })
        }
    });

    var CategoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:'.content',

        render:function(options){ 
            var that = this;
            alert(options.id);
            if(options.id){
                that.category = new Category({id : options.id});
                that.category.fetch({
                    success:function(category){
                        console.log(category.toJSON());
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is that in the CategoryView I get a list of Products , not sure how to map them to Product list. Please help me with a feasible solution.

I would like to understand if a backbone model can have a collection inside it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem fallowing your code, but generally if you have an array containing all the data needed by your collection you can simple create the collection and use it. On the other had if you have the id of the collection you can use fetch to retrieve the data. Here's a simple example to get you some idea
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5896152 if you have some time to spend it would be wise to watch Nick Gauthier video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqtYcHyyWJA
Two more recommendations: 1 it is customary for render to return this to enable chaining, the idiom this.$el.append(someView.render.el) is very common, and second why don't you initialize your data in the initialize method instead of render and just call render on success. Best of luck Slobodan